# Sort nodes of a NetworkX graph based on a node attribute

Tags: python, networkx

I have a nx Graph with few nodes. All these nodes have an attribute "dist". I want sorted list of nodes based on "dist" values at nodes. How can I get it?
I have tried:

```
 sorted(G.nodes(data=True))
```

But here I'm unable to pass node_attribute info on the basis of which I want to sort the nodes.

Also, if I have a list of nodes (a subset of all nodes), and I want to sort them on the basis of the same node attribute, is it possible
without sorting all the nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *key* argument to pass to pass a function to the *sorted* method. It will then sort the nodes based on the values returned by that function, so something like

```
sorted(G.nodes(), key=lambda n: G.nodes[n]['dist'])
```

should work. If you're sorting any subset of the nodes in the graph, you can still just do

```
sorted(list_of_nodes, key=lambda n: G.node[n]['dist'])
```

Comment: It's difficult to help if you don't write a specific example of what you want. I tried expanding on the answer,, but if you're looking for something else, please include an example in your question.

Comment: The correct one should be: `sorted(G.nodes(), key=lambda n: G.nodes[n]['dist'])` `G.nodes` instead of `G.node`